# Datagridview scrollbar in visibles rows

Tags: exception, datagridview, scrollbar, mousewheel, visible

I'm new in c# desktop.

I want to filtering a dataGridView with textbox changed , i have the solution to hidding the row  like this :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells["column1"].Value.ToString().Trim().Contains(textbox.Text.Trim()))
                    {
                        row.Visible = true;
                   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        
                        row.Visible = false;
                
                 
                    }
                   
                }
```

My problem is :
and i have this Exception :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8ZXb.png)
and i cant use datagridview.datasource=dt;
So please what is the solution to make the scrollbar and the mousewheel scrolling in my datagridview
Thanks;

Comment: *i cant use datagridview.datasource=dt* - why not?

Comment: Because the header name  of columns of gridview are different with the columns of datatable , i have changement in the gridview ... and the type of columns are not the same .

Comment: That doesn't have to be a blocker to using a datatable as the underlying data source

Comment: i know but this will change the process of code . datasource will be the last solution .

Comment: It is unclear “where” the posted code is executed. From my tests, if there is NO data source, I am unable to get the error shown. The error appears to be thrown “before” the grid has been initialized which is confusing and needs calirity as to “where” the posted code is run. If you use a data source, then the code fails if there are no rows shown after the filter. As Caius mentions, your reasoning for NOT using a `DataTable` does not hold water.

Comment: You commented that… _”Because the header name of columns of gridview are different with the columns of datatable”_ … then use the columns `DataPropertyName` to match the column in the table to the column in the grid, the column names do not have to match. Also … _”i have changement in the gridview ... and the type of columns are not the same”_ ? … the column “type” in the grid can be a simple “text” column and the grid will honor what ever “type” the column is in the table. Is there a column of some “special” type?

Comment: Lastly, it is unclear “why” you want to manage this “filter” manually which will be more work for you. I suggest the easiest way to filter the grid rows is to set a data source, then simply “filter” the data source. This will take care of what rows are displayed without you having to set individual rows “invisible.” Your approach is creating more work for you and exposes the application to more errors like the one you are seeing now.

Comment: Hello JohnG, Thanks for your comments , 
All i want is there a solution to scrolling in hidden rows .
If there is no solution i will change to datasource.

Comment: You need to clarify _”solution to scrolling in hidden rows”_  ?  As I stated already, if there is “no” data source to the grid, the posted code works without errors when “scrolling” hidden rows (whatever that means) … even if “all” the rows were hidden... in which case, there is really nothing to scroll.  However, if a data source “is” used, the code throws an error when “all” rows are hidden. This error is coming from the “new” row if users are allowed to add rows.

Comment: This is where I am confused, as you state there is no data source and if so, even with allowing users to add new rows…  I cannot reproduce the error you describe. I am betting that wherever you are running the posted code, one of the rows is not able to be set as “hidden/invisible.” The only row I can think of that would fall into this category is the “new” row. I know that _”All i want is there a solution to scrolling in hidden rows”_ …and the answer is YES. Now, Can you answer my question that I started with… “where” is the posted code executed/run?